# regular expression get all hosts from html

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to get all urls in one regular expression, currently i'm using this pattern.

```
/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/
```

However that regex returns the pages/files, instead of hosts. So instead of having to run a second regular expression, I'm hoping someone here can help

This returns `http://www.yoursite.com/index.html`

I'm attempting to return `yoursite.com`.

Also the the regex will be parsing from html and hosts will be checked after, so 100% accuracy isn't crucial.

Comment: I appreciate your effort but why don't you use solutions already provided in .NET?http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx

Comment: Do you want to show us at least a sample of your source text and then what you expect and what you are getting? It makes it much easier to understand...

Comment: This pattern returns nothing, can you show us a real try

Comment: It would be better to just use the Uri class to parse it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your regex:

```
/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/
```

Actually does parse the Urls (I haven't checked it), you could easily use a capture group to get the host:

```
/^(https?:\/\/)?(?<host>([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6}))([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/
```

When you get the `Match` result, you can examine `Groups["host"]` to get the host name.

But you're much better off, in my opinion, just using [Uri.TryCreate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131572.aspx), although you'll need a little logic to get around the possible lack of a scheme. That is:

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(line, "https?:\/\/"))
    line = "http://" + line;
Uri uri;
if (Uri.TryCreate(line, UriKind.Absolute, out uri))
{
    // it's a valid url.
    host = uri.Host;
}
```

Parsing Urls is a pretty tricky business. For example, no individual dotted segment can exceed 63 characters, and there's nothing preventing the last dotted segment from having numbers or hyphens. Nor is it limited to 6 characters. You're better off passing the entire string to `Uri.TryCreate` than you are trying to duplicate the craziness of URL parsing with a single regular expression.

It's possible that the rest of the Url (after the host name) could be trash. If you want to eliminate that bit causing a problem, then extract everything up to the end of the host name:

```
^https?:\/\/[^\/]*
```

Then run that through `Uri.TryCreate`.

Answer (score 0):

To capture just the `yoursite.com` from sample text `http://www.yoursite.com/index?querystring=value`  you could use this expression, however this does not validate the string:

`^(https?:\/\/)?(?:[^.\/?]*[.])?([^.\/?]*[.][^.\/?]*)`

[image]

Live demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/UNR7qiQ0Eq